# Serialization of complex structures in C++

Tags: c++, struct

I'm trying to serialize a set of structs in C++. This works great for all data except a vector contained in my struct. I can write the data to disk, and then read all data back into memory. The only problem is when I try to access an element of the vector I get a segmentation fault. My code is below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Program to write to disk

```
int main {
  struct Student one;
  strcpy(one.FullName, "Ernestine Waller");
  strcpy(one.CompleteAddress, "824 Larson Drv, Silver Spring, MD 20910");
  one.Gender = 'F';
  one.LivesInASingleParentHome = true;
  one.grades.push_back(80);
  one.grades.push_back(90);

  ofstream ofs("fifthgrade.ros", ios::binary);
  ofs.write((char *)&one, sizeof(one));
  ofs.close();
}
```

Program to read from disk

```
 int main {
    struct Student *two = (struct Student *) malloc(sizeof(struct Student));    
    ifstream ifs("fifthgrade.ros", ios::binary);
    //cout << "Size of struct: " << size << endl;
    ifs.read((char *)two, sizeof(struct Student));
    cout << "Student Name: " << two->FullName << endl;
    cout << "First Grade: " <<  two->grades[0] << endl;
    cout << "Second Grade: " << two->grades[1] << endl;
    ifs.close();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/serialization.html

Comment: Boost serialization: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: Please include the declaration for `Student`

Comment: That looks like homeworks ... plus it is more C than C++ ... Hint : look for unallocated part of the struct Student

Comment: Oh my! You are mixing C and C++, `malloc` to allocate dynamically elements at the same time that you mix it with `std::vector` inside the struct... You should really go back to basics and start with a simple C++ tutorial. As it is, your program is most probably in Undefined Behavior land... (hint: when is the `std::vector` inside the `Student` struct initialized?)

Comment: Oh godness... You need to review the concept of serialization and the differences between C and C++. There are questions on this site that recommends list of readings to learn about C++, which would greatly benefit you. As it is, your program needs a complete rewrite.

Comment: @dribeas: Doesn't matter as long as he doesn't need to call a constructor/destructor.

Answer (score 8):

What you are doing is taking copying a contiguous region of memory in which you have stored `one` and wrote it to disk. This will work fine for simple data types (POD in C++ jargan). The problem with vectors is that a vector is a complex object with pointers to other regions of memory. These other regions of memory don't exist when you de-serialize `one` into `two` hence your segmentation fault.

Unfortunately there is no shortcut, some form on custom serialization code will need to be written to get the job done.

As some have already mentioned [Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) may help. Alternatively roll out your own.

Answer (score 5):

Probably the simplest version of serializing a vector that stands a chance of working is something like:

```
your_stream << your_vector.size();
std::copy(your_vector.begin(), your_vector.end(),
     std::ostream_iterator<your_vector::value_type>(your_stream, "\n"));
```

Reading it back goes something like:

```
size_t size;
your_stream >> size;
vector_two.resize(size);
for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
    your_stream >> vector_two[i];
```

Note that this is not particularly efficient -- in particular, it (basically) assumes the data will be stored in text format, which is often fairly slow and takes up extra space (but is easy to read, manipulate, etc., by outside programs, which is often useful).