# C++ : serializing a vector of class instances

Tags: c++, serialization, vector

I want to save a vector of class instances to a file, to be able to load them in later.

This is how the class looks like (roughly):

```
class outer{
    public:
        int a;
        class inner{
            public:
                int a;
                inner(int a){
                     this->a = a;
                }
        };

        vector<inner> all_inners;
        outer(int a){
            this->a = a;
            all_inners.push_back(inner(this->a+1));
        }
};
```

The vector of class `outer` instances, and how it might be populated:

```
vector<outer> all_outers;
int i;
void some_function(){
    for(i=0; i<5;i++)
        all_outers.push_back(outer(i));
}
```

I want to serialize the `all_outers` vector to a file, and when I read it back in, I'd like to have the exact same state of the class instances (including the inner class instances) as it was when written to the file.
Is something like this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523832/serialization-of-complex-structures-in-c

Comment: If you say _serialize_, do you want to save a text format, or binary data? The former could be handled by overwriting `std::ostream operator<<()`, and `std::istream operator>>()` specialized for your class.

Comment: I want it in binary format..

Answer (score 1):

You can write outers size, and after that write each outer using the following function. After that you can read each outer back using read function.

```
void write(ostream& os, outer a)
{
  os.write((const char*)a.a(), sizeof(int));
  // write inners size
  os.write((const char*)a.all_inners.size(), sizeof(size_t));
  for(const inner& in : a.all_inners)
  {
    os.write((const char*)in.a, sizeof(int));
  }
}

void read(istream& is, outer& a)
{
  is.read((char*)a.a, sizeof(int));
  size_t size;
  is.read((char*)size, sizeof(size_t));
  a.all_inners.resize(size);
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    int value;
    is.read((char*)value, sizeof(int));
    a.all_inners[i].a = value;
  }
}
```